# not saving "add rows" or adding a custom option Magento 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento1.9.2.3

it appears it is saving and even says it saved, when in fact it is NOT saving when I add a row or even a custom option when editing my product. No matter what changes I make to this product it won't save. This is any NEW things I am saving or adding to the product. Weird how this is affecting only some product and "not" other products too.